# How to implement iOS Data Protection on iOS 8 app by XCode 6.1 project->targets->Capabilities->Data Protection?

Tags: ios, security, core-data, data-protection

I found some legacy questions with dinosaur answers about implement Data Protection. I hear there are differents since iOS7 or iOS8. Do we still need coding after turn on the Data Protection capability in XCode 6?

Is this necessary?

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[self filePath]
                                        contents:[@"super secret file contents" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                      attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete
                                                                         forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]];
 [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[self filePath]
                                                   error:NULL] 
                                             valueForKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
```

And, how can we protect Core Data with this Data Protection?

OR, is this an one button solution for protect data in phone lock state?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf for `NSFileProtectionComplete`,

> The class key is protected with a key derived from the user passcode
>   and the device UID. Shortly after the user locks a device (10 seconds,
>   if the Require Password setting is Immediately), the decrypted class
>   key is discarded, rendering all data in this class inaccessible until
>   the user enters the passcode again or unlocks the device using Touch
>   ID.

So, when you create your persistent store using:

`- (NSPersistentStore *)addPersistentStoreWithType:(NSString *)storeType configuration:(NSString *)configuration URL:(NSURL *)storeURL options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError **)error;`

pass in your file protection options as part of the options dictionary.